# Can't set pulse audio as KDE default

Tags: kde, pulse-audio

I am running Arch Linux and KDE4. I installed the pulseaudio deamon on a remote machine with an external soundcard. From the local machine's terminal I can stream audio to that machine without any problem (using `play foo.wav`). When I set the PulseAudio Sound Server device as Phonon defualt output I don't get any sound from KDE. 
To carify: If I use the test button I get no sound, but it works for other applications like flash or from the CLI.
I am using Gstreamer as backend for Phonon.

What are possible sources of error and how can I find out what's wrong?